# Removing duplicate git commits caused by filter-branch

Tags: git

I've seen this posted a few times but there aren't any solid answers on actually how to solve it.

I went and ran this on my branch to rewrite author history:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
OLD_EMAIL="your-old-email@example.com"
CORRECT_NAME="Your Correct Name"
CORRECT_EMAIL="your-correct-email@example.com"
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

I then issued `git push --force --tags origin 'refs/heads/*'` and thought everything went well. Until I opened SourceTree and saw I had a bunch of commits to pull so I pulled then pushed without thinking. What it probably did was issue another push without `--force` and now nearly every commit is duplicated.

I attempted to rebase in interactive mode using `rebase -i HEAD~` but it orders the commits based on ancestor history (or something similar) making it nearly impossible to squash duplicate commits, which are in the hundreds on master.

Is there a way to correct this in an answerable fashion?

Comment: `and saw I had a bunch of commits to pull` ... this sounds like maybe others were still adding things to this remote branch while you were running filter branch.  Either that, or you didn't `git pull` properly before starting the filter branch.  In any case, you shouldn't have done that pull.  Basically, since you rewrote the branch's history, force pushing is really the only thing you could have done at that point.

Comment: I don't understand what happened exactly, but I know I had the latest copy of master before I did the operation and no other users were pushing changes to the branch. The question is really what to do about it at this point. It's interesting to point out that `rebase -i HEAD` just returns a noop as well.

Comment: I partially take back what I said.  The reason Git was saying that you were behind the remote branch _is_ because you rewrote the history of that branch.  But, you absolutely should _not_ have done `git pull`...that was a big error.  I don't know how to fix this; I would just go back and start over if I were you.

Comment: indeed a big error.

Comment: You might able to just nuke off the commits which came in when you did the `git pull`.  This assumes that you pulled with the merge strategy, and not the rebase strategy.

Comment: Filter branch does not (because it cannot) *change* commits, so it fundamentally *must* copy commits. If you re-introduce the original commits from the original repository or any of its clones, you see exactly this behavior. Essentially, after filtering, all existing clones of the filtered repository must be shunned forevermore. That said, you can typically just reset away the merge, then resume the shunning. :-)

Comment: I tried using `rebase -i <commit>` and deleting all of the duplicate commits by message (man there were a lot) but ended up abandoning the attempt as something didn't go right. At the end there was a conflict and a few files were changed - I'm guessing that I had deleted a merge commit with the same message or something. No easy answers here.